# query based on column Name provided by user

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Student` with the records as follows.

```
StudentId int PK NOT Null, 
Name Varchar(50),
Age int,
DateofBirth Datetime and 
ClassRecordID int NOT NULL
MajorID int NOT NULL
```

And the data looks like this:

```
StudentID   Name      Age    Dateofbirth  ClassRecordID   MajorID
1234        Sam       21     1/10/1991        1122          1
1235        NULL      Null   1/12/1990        1123          2
1236        George    Null   NULL             1125          2
1237        Fanny     NULL   NULL             1155          1
```

My Requirement is ,

Whenever the user provides a `columnName` and `MajorID`, the query should return the `classRecordID` from the table for which the specified `columnName` has null or empty values.

For example,

When the user provides `columnName = 'Age'` and `MajorId = 2`, the query should return 1123 and 1125.

Similarly, when the user provides `columnName = 'Dateofbirth'` and `MajorId = 2`, the query should return  1125.

I tried using the following query,

```
Declare @ColumnName nvarchar(50)
Delcare @MajorId int

set @ColumnName = 'age' --for example
set @MajorId = 2 -- For example

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
   ClassRecordID
FROM
   dbo.Student WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
   (@ColumnName IS NULL 
    OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ColumnName))) = 0)
   AND 
   MajorId = @MajorId
```

But it returns empty instead of expected results. What is wrong with this query? Is there any better way to do this? I don't want to use IF else approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to be able to filter by arbitrary column without having to extend your code every time a new column is added, you could use dynamic SQL and `sp_executesql`. This code snippet should work for you:

```
declare @nullFilterColumnName varchar(50)
set @nullFilterColumnName = 'Age'

declare @majorId int
set @majorId = 2

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select distinct ClassRecordID from Students where isnull('
    + quotename(@nullFilterColumnName)
    + ', '''') = '''' and MajorId = '
    + cast(@majorId as nvarchar(20))
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

But I'd suggest to use this option as a last resort. @ron tornambe's version is more robust.

Comment: I'll take this as an answer. Thank you Yuriy.

Comment: Glad I could help you. It would be nice if you 'accepted' this answer (see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)).

Comment: A `]` in a name should be escaped by being repeating twice (e.g. a name like `X[1]` should be referenced in queries as `[X[1]]]`). So it's not always enough to just enclose the name in square brackets. If you are unsure if a `]` may be present or not, you can use [`QUOTENAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx "QUOTENAME (Transact-SQL)"), just to be on the safe side. It both delimits the name and adds escaping as necessary. That is, instead of `'... [' + @name + '] ...'` use `'... ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + ' ...'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this technique is the one you seek:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
    ClassRecordID
FROM
    dbo.Student WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    1 = CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'Age' THEN
            CASE WHEN Age IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ELSE CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'DateofBirth' THEN
            CASE WHEN DateOfBirth IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END                    
AND MajorId = @MajorId
```

Comment: I tried this solution but It won't provide me the flexibility provided by Yuriy's approach. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. Before adopting a dynamic-sql approach, you may wish to see this article: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html to determine if it is a proper fit for your situation.

Comment: Sure Ron, I'll have a look on it.